# i am having trouble with this piecewise integral

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

$$let\ f(x)=\begin{cases}
1-x,x\in[0,2]\\
x-3,x\in[2,4]\\
x+5,x\in[4,6]
\end{cases}\ and\ g(x)=\int_0^xf(t)dt$$
then:
1)sketch the graph of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$
2)does there exist a value c where $\frac{1}{2}g(2)=f(c)$ and if it does what is it
3)does there exist a value c where $\frac{1}{4}g(4)=f(c)$ and if it does what is it
4)does there exist a value c where $\frac{1}{6}g(6)=f(c)$ and if it does what is it
5)does there exist a value for any $x \in (0,6]$ such that$\frac{1}{x}g(x)=f(c)$ and if it does what is it

so at first i tried basically getting $g(x)$ by integration
so for values of $x$ between $0$ and $2$
$$g(x)=\int_0^xf(t)\ dt=\int_0^x1-t\ dt=x-\frac{1}{2}x^2$$
and for values of $x$ between $2$ and $4$
$$g(x)=\int_0^xf(t)\ dt=\int_0^21-t\ dt+\int_2^xt-3\ dt=\frac{1}{2}x^2-3x+4$$
and for values of $x$ between $4$ and $6$
$$g(x)=\int_0^xf(t)\ dt=\int_0^21-t\ dt+\int_2^4t-3\ dt+\int_4^xt+5\ dt=\frac{1}{2}x^2+5x-28$$
and i got the values $g(2)=0$ and $g(4)=0$ and $g(6)=20$
so from the second question
\begin{align*}
    &\frac{1}{2}g(2)=f(c)=0\\
    &f(c)=0\to 1-c=0\to c=1 \in [0,2]\\
    &f(c)=0\to c-3=0\to c=3 \in [2,4]\\
    &f(c)=0\to c+5=0\to c=-5 \notin [4,6]\\
\end{align*}
so $c=1$ and $c=3$ in the second question
we will get the same numbers in the third question as $g(2)=g(4)=0$
and for the fourth i didn't find any c that satisfies the condition
and the fifth idk what to do i am confused

Comment: There is a little issue with your $f$.  What is $f(4)$?

Comment: i don't know i wrote the question as in my pdf

Comment: but i think its just a mistake from the teacher and one of the brackets must be open i hope this doesn't affect the answer

Comment: Hint: you're establishing the necessary conditions for the [mean value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#First_mean_value_theorem_for_definite_integrals)